# Javascript Image not Drawing on Canvas after Drawing it to Offscreen Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have an Image that I would like to render to a canvas. When I render it like so:

```
context.drawImage(image, x, y);
```

It works as expected. However when I do this:

```
if (image.loaded)
    image = getPreRendered(image);
...
var renderedImages = [];
var tmpImage = null;
function getPreRendered(img) {
    imageIndex = ("" + img.src);
    tmpImage  = cachedSprays[tmpIndex];
    if (tmpImage == undefined) {
        var tmpCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var tmpContext = tmpCanvas.getContext('2d');
        tmpCanvas.width = 50;
        tmpCanvas.height = 50;
        tmpContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        tmpContext.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        tmpContext.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        tmpContext.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
        tmpContext.drawImage(tmpCanvas, 0, 0, 50, 50, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        tmpImage = tmpCanvas;
        cachedSprays[imageIndex] = tmpImage ;
    }
    return tmpImage ;
}
```

When I do this however, the image is no longer visible on the canvas.

The image is created like this:

```
var image = new Image();
image.loaded = false;
image.onload = function () {
    image.loaded = true;
};
```

Comment: JS is async. An image will/would load but you already called that function while the image was still loading.

Comment: Check what the console says ?

Comment: could you show more of your code ? what is `tmpIndex` ? why do you check in a loop if your image has loaded instead of calling the `getPreRendered` directly in the onload callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX and image calls are **asyncronous**. An image will/would load but you already called that function while the image was still loading.

```
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function () {
    // call here your render canvas function:
    getPreRendered( image );
};
image.src = "nOOdes.jpg"
```

Comment: getPreRendered(image) function is called within a game loop. So it will attempt to pre-render it continuously.

Comment: Strictly speaking JS is not asynchronous, only the some DOM elements and various APIs (such as Image) are asynchronous. Pure Javascript can not do anything asynchronously.

Comment: @Blindman67 Thanks for noticing. I meant something else and slopped the answer. OFC JS is strictly syncronous, it's the AJAX and requests that aren't.

Comment: I fixed it by using this solution. But it is strange since the caching was done in a loop, and it should only have been called once the load completed; .loaded = true.